# Identify fields with RFC822 Internet mail text using Formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have some documents who have a field called `From` and some of them have RFC822 Internet mail text. Its contents are displayed the document properties something like this:

```
Field Name: From
Data Type: RFC822 Text
Data Length: XX bytes
Seq Num: 2
Dup Item ID: 0

Field Flags: SUMMARY NAMES 

RFC822 Type: ADDRESS
RFC822 Flags: STRICT 
Native Value: 

"ABC XYZ <ABCXYZ@PQR.COM>"

RFC822 Header Name: 

"From"

RFC822 Header Delimiter: 

": "

RFC822 Header Body: 

4E 79 6A 52 19 ABC 
6F 59 6F 60 32 XYZ
...
...
```

In LotusScript I was able to write the following piece of code to identify if the field has RFC822 Internet mail text.

```
Set item = doc.Getfirstitem("From")
If item.Type = 1282 Then
    'Field has RFC822 Internet mail text
End If
```

But how can I check this in Formula Language? I cannot find any equivalent Formula code that would check for RFC822 Internet mail text. I am trying to identify fields of type RFC822 TEXT with the field properties shown similar to above. I need this so that I can put it into view selection formula and see all the documents in a single view.

Comment: I'm a bit confused over what you really want.  Are you trying to identifying fields of type "RFC822 TEXT" (as seen in the field list in the doc properties box)?  Or are you trying to identify fields that contain a valid address that conforms to the RFC822 address spec?  Or are you trying to identify fields that are of type RFC822 TEXT *and* contain a valid address that conforms to the RFC822 address spec?  Or something else, if I missed any possibilities here ;-)

Comment: I am trying to identify fields of type RFC822 TEXT with the field properties shown similar to my question. I need to somehow get all the documents with that kind of field value to be shown in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to check the field type in formula language.  Can you write a LotusScript agent to check item.Type and add a hidden field (e.g., $HasRFC822TextItems = 1), and use that for your view selection formula?

If you can't or don't want to do that, another alternative is to create a folder, and use that instead of a view.  I.e., have your agent test the item.Type as above, and then use NotesDocument.putInFolder("RFC 822 Text Documents").

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check if the item's value is in FRC822 format with this formula:

```
add := @ValidateInternetAddress([ADDRESS822];From) ;
x := @If( add = "" ; "RFC 822 ADDRESS" ; "OTHER ADDRESS FORMAT") ;
@Prompt([OK];"";x)
```

If the formula returns an empty string, the validation was successful or in other words: the value in the field From contains a valid RFC822 value.

It does not check the item's type though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. But the formula returns true if the field value contains just the value as `"ABC XYZ" <abcxyz@pqr.com>`. If it contains the value shown as in my question (which is visible in document properties) then it returns error message of `Invalid Phrase or character found.`

Comment: Hm, strange. I tried this against an email with a From field in the same format as described in your question. In that case it returns an empty string. When I try this against a From field with a Notes address, I get the error mentioned by you. So you could wrap my formula in an @If formula to catch this. I updated the code above a little bit.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Does it work for you in view selection formula? That is where I intend to use it.

Comment: I also updated my question to include complete field properties text.

Comment: I think the problem is that the address should be in the format: 
"Streitfeld, Sara (Miami)" <SStreitfeld@gazette.com> (from notes help). For your example that would mean a value of 
"ABC XYZ" <ABCXYZ@PQR.COM>
Otherwise the check fails (in my case, too).

Comment: Ohh... The format of email ID is same as I described in my question. I had only removed actual names, thats it. Back to square one I guess!

Comment: It's a bug in @ValidateInternetAddress with the [Address822] argument.  According to the RFC822 specs, the quotation marks are not required around ABC XYZ.  In the BNF in the spec, that part of the address is called the 'phrase', and a 'phrase' is defined as '1* word', which means one or more words. The quotes are required around "Streitfeld, Sara (Miami)" because it contains a comma, which is a delimiter.  (This is also true in RFC5322, which is the more up to date standard, although this version calls that part of the address the 'display-name', and then defines that as a 'phrase'.)

Comment: BTW: I haven't tried this in Notes 9 to see if the bug has been fixed.

Comment: I should add that most people would put the quotes around "ABC XYZ" because it's a convention that they see all the time and they think it's required.  And most software does too, and there's probably quite a bit of bad software out there that blows up if it receives an address without the quotes around the display-name.  So according to the standard, it really isn't required -- but it's still a good idea to use the quotes in order to insure that the address will be acceptable to all the bad software that's out there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and providing more details on the subject. In a perfect world my solution would be working - but as we all know, the world is not perfect ;-)